# Is Web API supporting pushing to clients?

Tags: push, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Is new Web API supporting pushing messages to clients (instead of continuous polling)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out of the box. Take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to enable this scenario.

Comment: I believe there are quite a bit of people using it. If you have questions, check out their jabbr room: http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr. Oh, Jabbr is built on SignalR.

Comment: @JakubKonecki it is more stable than WebSocets:) have a look: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2287